# FAIL to SELECT data from table that created by select statement in SQLPLUS

Tags: sql, select, sqlplus

This is my sql statement

it is used to "Find the average salary for each job title.  Show the job title and the amount of those that have the average salary amounts 3000 or higher."

```
CREATE TABLE avgSal AS (
SELECT job, AVG(sal) AS "sal" FROM Emp GROUP BY job);

SELECT * FROM avgSal WHERE sal>3000;
```

then sqlplus say

```
ORA-00904: "SAL": invalid identifier
```

After I enter the second sql statement

Can someone give me some help? /(T_T)\

And this is my **first** time to use stackoverflow  (-,-)/

Comment: maybe check the capitalization of your fields, sometime it makes different.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! :) this seems like a bad idea in the first place... what happens if the EMP table gets updated? you would have to update this table too? why not just make it a temporary table that you can query off of when you only need to and always have updated data? try putting backticks on your column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You quoted the column name `"sal"` and therefor it is case-sensitive.

You must quote the column when referencing it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM avgSal 
WHERE "sal" > 3000;
```

In general it's better to avoid quoted identifiers.

More details about identifiers can be found in the manual:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223

But you don't really need to create a table in order to achieve what you want:

```
select *
from (
  SELECT job, 
         avg(sal) AS avg_sal 
  FROM Emp 
  GROUP BY job
) t
where avg_sal > 3000;
```

Another option is to use a common table expression:

```
with avgSal as (
  SELECT job, 
         avg(sal) AS avg_salary
  FROM Emp 
  GROUP BY job
) 
select *
form avgSal
where avg_salary > 3000;
```

Comment: Only thing to note here is that MySQL doesn't support the `with` operator incase thats what the OP is using.. but regardless +1 from me :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell: the error message clearly shows the OP is using Oracle.

Comment: Oh my bad i didnt even see that... nvm then :)

Comment: Thank you very much. (^v^)/   And I wish I could vote for your answer someday.